# Spring boot user authenticate with keycloak (microservices)

Tags: java, spring, jwt, microservices, keycloak

I'm trying to re-build monolith app with microservices. Now I'm trying to make in-app authorization based on JWT. Approximate diagram is next:
[image: Microservice diagram 1]

*RootService* uses to manage users (create, update, delete) and other different entities.
So what I want to do is make user-authorization service with **keycloak** using **RootService**, so it should look something like this:
[image: Microservice diagram 2]
In keycloak I created realm and **one client** for gateway service  using next parameters:
[image: client params]

Current client gives ability to generate JWT and communicate between service, but how can I manage user access with keycloak using roles and so one? Should I create another client and generate some token for **gateway client** or I can use same created client and can create users via keycloak?

If there is any good article or guide - I'll be grateful for some resources. Thanks for replies!